# Cloud messaging solution for webpage notification without asking for permission

Tags: php, jquery, service-worker

I need to show alerts to my web page. My website is developed in php and to get notification messages I am calling an API. I tried SignalOne, Firebase . .. they are working fine . but I need the notifications to appear bydefault. The code I tried is asking for permission ..

I need some suggestions:
1. Is there any plugin that can help me achieve my requirement
2. Should I prepare a service worker by myself .. if yes then is it possible to read API reasult through

Answer (score 1):

Web Push Notification always need the permission of the user, there is no way around. It is the same when you write your service worker yourself.

Have a look at this article, it describes how to set up an nice permission UX with the goal that the user understands better why to grant push notification and therefore he will more likely allow them.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/permission-ux